# Indexing on a single value only in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table in which I use reference counting for removing obsolete rows. In order to do this efficiently, I would like to create an index that only indexes the rows in the table, where the reference count is 0. Is this possible, or am I better off using a view, or something else?

Comment: Depends on which **version** of SQL Server you're using - version **2008** and newer have filtered indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a Filtered Index. Maybe something like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex
ON MyTable(MyColumn)
WHERE ReferenceCount = 0
```

You can learn more about them [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/01/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-filtered-index-improve-performance-with-filtered-index/)